# True proportion in data from different institutions

Tags: effect-size

I have individual patient level data about mortality from many several institutions so, I can directly calculate the whole dataset mortality. I was wandering if there is any method to cope with differential institutions variability, provided they are located at different regions and have (plausibly) different standard of care. The number of patients from each institution varies widely.
For example, is it valid to meta-analyze data considering each institution as a different "study"?

Comment: I would have thought a meta-analysis would bring together different studies rather than create them.  But there are certainly ways of studying the whole dataset which draws out the different institutions and can if you wish look at interactions between these and other variables of interest. It is a deep subject and difficult to condense down to an answer to a single question.  It would be better practice to decide what you are considering and how, after you know what data is available but before you look at all the actual numbers